# Always push content down when changing a div's height without changing the page position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with a `div` in the middle of content, whose height can change from javascript.

How can I control which way the page will scroll when the div height's changes? I want content to be always pushed down, never up.

Currently, the content is pushed down or up, depending on where the page scroll is when the button is clicked.

Here is a minimal example:

```js
function toggle(ev) {
    const div = document.querySelector("div");
    if (div.style.height === "336px") {
      div.style.height = "147px";
    } else {
        div.style.height = "336px";
    }
}
```

```css
body {max-width: 60em; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<p style="background-color: coral; height: 400px;"></p>
<div style="background-color:grey; height: 147px;"></div>
<button href="#" onclick="toggle()">toggle div size</button>
<p style="background-color: olive; height: 3000px;"></p>
```

To make things clearer, I'm looking for a solution where the top paragraph never moves when the div expands, no matter where on the window the button currently is. i.e. the bottom paragraph should be move up/down as well as the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try blurring the element (e.target.blur() on click handler) to make it inactive before updating the height of the content. Since the window no longer sees the button as active, it will no longer scroll the page to keep it in view.

```
const handleClick = e => {
    e.target.blur()
    updateScrollHeight()
}
```

```js
function toggle(ev) {
    const div = document.querySelector("div");
    ev.target.blur();
    if (div.style.height === "336px") {
      div.style.height = "147px";
    } else {
        div.style.height = "336px";
    }
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

```css
body {max-width: 60em; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<p style="background-color: coral; height: 400px;"></p>
<div style="background-color:grey; height: 147px;"></div>
<button href="#">toggle div size</button>
<p style="background-color: olive; height: 3000px;"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to scroll at the bottom every time you set the height

```
function toggle(ev) {
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  if (div.style.height === "336px") {
    div.style.height = "147px";
  } else {
      div.style.height = "336px";
  }
  div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight
}
```

Comment: No I don't want to scroll the page nor the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the selected element using `window.scrollTo` function.

```html
<!doctype html>

<style>
    body {max-width: 60em; margin: auto;}
</style>

<script>
function toggle(ev) {
    const div = document.querySelector("div");
    if (div.style.height === "336px") {
      div.style.height = "147px";
    } else {
        div.style.height = "336px";
    }
    window.scrollTo(0, div.scrollHeight);
}
</script>

<p style="background-color: coral; height: 400px;"></p>
<div style="background-color:grey; height: 147px;"></div>
<button href="#" onclick="toggle()">toggle div size</button>
<p style="background-color: olive; height: 3000px;"></p>
```

Comment: No I don't want to scroll the page. If the top paragraph is already in view it should not move at all.

Answer (score 0):

The page is keeping the currently active element in view - i.e. the button that you clicked on - so the extra height will appear to move up or down depending on where the button is in relation to the screen.

What you want to do is to make the page look like it didn't scroll up after the element expanded. To do this we can just scroll the page *back to the position it was before the element expanded* - this makes it look as if the height expanded downwards.

**1. Save the current position of the top of the page**

```
var pagePosBeforeExpand = window.pageYOffset;
```

**2. Scroll the page back to the position it was before we changed the height**, if the div has been expanded:

```
// if we are increasing the height, then scroll to the previous top...
window.scrollTo({ top: pagePosBeforeExpand });
```

**Note that this doesn't affect when you collapse the height again** as you didn't ask for that in your question, however you could adapt this to suit in that scenario - e.g. you could simply move the scroll code to execute outside of the `if`.

**Working Example:**

```js
function toggle(ev) {
    // 1. Save the current position of the top of the page
    var pagePosBeforeExpand = window.pageYOffset;

    const div = document.querySelector("div");
    if (div.style.height === "336px") {
      div.style.height = "147px";
    } else {
        div.style.height = "336px";
        // 2. scroll the page back to the position it was beforewe changed the height
        window.scrollTo({ top: pagePosBeforeExpand })
    }
}
```

```css
body {max-width: 60em; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<p style="background-color: coral; height: 400px;"></p>
<div style="background-color:grey; height: 147px;">Top of content</div>
<button href="#" onclick="toggle()">toggle div size</button>
<p style="background-color: olive; height: 3000px;"></p>
```

Comment: This is not the solution I'm looking for because it moves the entire page.The behavior I want is the same as in my example, even when the button is near the top of the window. i.e. the top paragraph should never move.

Comment: @fouronnes I misunderstood what you were trying to do, however the explanation in my answer is still accurate so we know what is happening and I'll edit the answer to work the way you need

Comment: Still not what I'm looking for. I'd like that when the div height changes the bottom paragraph and button move, but not the top paragraph.

Comment: @fouronnes I hadn't updated my answer when you checked before. I've updated my answer since and it works the way you want - you can see it if you expand the snippet to full page. The default action is for the page to scroll so the button doesn't move, so you will need to scroll the page back to where you want and this is the way to do it :)